# Why there is no sudoers file: "/etc/sudoers: No such file or directory"?

Tags: debian, user-accounts, administrator, sudo, sudoers

I am trying to add a new admin user, but:

```
# adduser username admin
  adduser: The user `username' does not exist.
# man sudoers
  No manual entry for sudoers
# less /etc/sudoers
  /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
```

The system is Debian 7 (Wheezy)
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the file there if you cd to /etc and use the ls command?

Comment: Is the `sudo` package actually installed?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sudo is not installed by default on Debian systems. You should issue as root:

`apt-get install sudo`

Other than that, adding a new user with a default group is done with:

`useradd -G groupname username`